Command failed with error 18 (AuthenticationFailed): 'Authentication failed.'
Even after providing the correct credentials in the flinkSql code still getting the authentication exception. Please find the exception below. Have tried the python code to connect to the mongo db and it worked. When it comes to flink getting the authentication exception.
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='airwave_user', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.wrapException(SaslAuthenticator.java:273)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.getNextSaslResponse(SaslAuthenticator.java:137)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.access$100(SaslAuthenticator.java:48)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:63)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:57)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.doAsSubject(SaslAuthenticator.java:280)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:57)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultAuthenticator.authenticate(DefaultAuthenticator.java:55)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.authenticate(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:205)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.finishHandshake(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:79)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:170)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.open(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:53)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.open(DefaultConnectionPool.java:495)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$OpenConcurrencyLimiter.openOrGetAvailable(DefaultConnectionPool.java:855)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$OpenConcurrencyLimiter.openOrGetAvailable(DefaultConnectionPool.java:805)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:154)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:144)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer.getConnection(DefaultServer.java:92)
    at com.mongodb.internal.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClusterBinding.java:141)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.ClientSessionBinding$SessionBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClientSessionBinding.java:163)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.lambda$executeCommand$4(CommandOperationHelper.java:190)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withReadConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:583)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:189)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.ListDatabasesOperation.execute(ListDatabasesOperation.java:201)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.ListDatabasesOperation.execute(ListDatabasesOperation.java:54)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:184)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.execute(MongoIterableImpl.java:135)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.iterator(MongoIterableImpl.java:92)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.forEach(MongoIterableImpl.java:121)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MappingIterable.forEach(MappingIterable.java:59)
    at org.apache.flink.cdc.connectors.mongodb.source.utils.CollectionDiscoveryUtils.databaseNames(CollectionDiscoveryUtils.java:61)
    at org.apache.flink.cdc.connectors.mongodb.internal.MongoDBConnectorSourceTask.initCapturedCollections(MongoDBConnectorSourceTask.java:284)
    at org.apache.flink.cdc.connectors.mongodb.internal.MongoDBConnectorSourceTask.start(MongoDBConnectorSourceTask.java:113)
    at io.debezium.embedded.EmbeddedEngine.run(EmbeddedEngine.java:760)
    at io.debezium.embedded.ConvertingEngineBuilder$2.run(ConvertingEngineBuilder.java:192)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18 (AuthenticationFailed): 'Authentication failed.' on server njbbairwpd1.nss.vzwnet.com:27009. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Authentication failed.", "code": 18, "codeName": "AuthenticationFailed"}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:195)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:398)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:319)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:88)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:36)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.sendSaslStart(SaslAuthenticator.java:228)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.getNextSaslResponse(SaslAuthenticator.java:135)
    ... 36 more


Please find the implemented code below. Flink version is 1.19.0
public class mongoDB {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env =StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.setParallelism(1);
    
    StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env);


    String sqlToRun = "CREATE TABLE flinkSql1 ("
            +"_id String,"
            + "Name String,"
            + "Age String,"
            + "PRIMARY KEY(_id) NOT ENFORCED"
            + ") WITH ("
            + "'connector' = 'mongodb-cdc',"
            + "'hosts' = 'nghj.com:27009',"
            + "'username' = 'user',"
            + "'password' = 'dX2Y?aqs',"
            + "'database' = 'sson',"
            + "'collection' = 'flinkSql',"
            + "'connection.options' = 'authSource=admin'"
            +")";
    
    tableEnv.executeSql(sqlToRun);

    
    String insertQuery = "SELECT * FROM flinkSql1";
    
    TableResult result = tableEnv.executeSql(insertQuery);
    result.print();
    try
    {
        env.execute("Job Submission");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}

Please find the dependencies used
<dependencies>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-api-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-mongodb-cdc</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-api-java-bridge</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>      


Your code doesn't show any information about how it connects to mongodb, or how the user credentials are specified.

Hi @Joe, Please find the code where I am creating the sqlToRun. As the part of the variable we are giving all the details."'connector' = 'mongodb-cdc',"
+ "'hosts' = 'nghj.com:27009',"
+ "'username' = 'user',"
+ "'password' = 'dX2Y?aqs',"
+ "'database' = 'sson',"
+ "'collection' = 'flinkSql',"
+ "'connection.options' = 'authSource=admin'"

Your mongo password contains special character. KIndly endoe the password before creating connection.

Hi @AanchalMehrotra, I tried with by taking the value to supress the special character and used like this "dX2Y%3Faqs".  Still getting the same error.
